# Qual é a origem da expressão "matar bodiões " relacionado com dormir?

Tags: significado, expressões, português-europeu, significado-em-contexto

Qual é a origem da expressão "matar bodiões" relacionada com dormir?

Ouço muito esta expressão na Madeira.

Comment: [Qual é a origem etc. ouço, ouvir.] Isso tudo se procura, né? Madeira.

Comment: PRIBERAM: 
pescar bodiões
• [Portugal: Madeira, Informal]  Dormitar ou cabecear de sono (ex.: está em frente à televisão a pescar bodiões).

"bodião", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/bodi%C3%A3o [consultado em 10-01-2022]. Por favor, procura no Priberam primeiro antes de postar.

Comment: Podes colocar o International Keyboard no computador.

Comment: Será  que ficam muito tempo à espera da prsca que dá  tempo de dormir ?

Comment: Não entendo o comentário.

Answer (score 3):

A expressão é um regionalismo portanto a origem por definição é um grupo de pessoas numa região geográfica delimitada terem começado a usar a expressão, da wikipedia:

> [Regionalismo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regionalismo_(lingu%C3%ADstica)) é o conjunto das particularidades linguísticas de uma determinada região geográfica, decorrentes da cultura lá existente.

Parabéns ao autor da pergunta porque de momento [*"matar bodiões"*](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22matar+bodi%C3%B5es%22) tem um único resultado no Google; é esta pergunta! A forma mais comum parece ser [*"pescar bodiões"*](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22pescar+bodi%C3%B5es%22) que tem 11 resultados no Google e [um video do Salvador Sobral](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=302586253670508) no Facebook a anunciar um espetáculo na Madeira.

De resto no Google books vem indexada um ocorrência da expressão no livro [*"Apontamentos sobre o quotidiano madeirense, 1750-1900"* de António Ribeiro Marques da Silva. Caminho, 1994.](https://books.google.pt/books/about/Apontamentos_sobre_o_quotidiano_madeiren.html?id=UTMkAQAAIAAJ) Talvez tenha um referência com data do uso da expressão, sem consultar publicações em papel e só usando a internet é difícil dizer mais.

Comment: será que de tanto esperar pelo peixe , adormece?!

Comment: @ClMend acho que sim, normalmente no continente associamos a pesca à cana com dormir a sesta enquanto se vai esperando que *"o peixe pique o anzol"*.  Portanto a imagem do pescador lúdico (não os profissionais nem os mergulhadores) a adormecer enquanto pesca é uma imagem comum. Se quiseres que eu inclua este comentário na resposta avisa, é tão intuitivo que nem pensei acrescentar...

Comment: Priberam mostra a expressão. Muito melhor do que google.

Comment: @bad_coder ,sim penso que ficaria melhor

Comment: @bad_coder, "no continente associamos a pesca à cana com dormir a sesta"?!... Fala por ti!

Comment: @Jacinto então pois claro, pesca à cana subentende pesca de água doce. Se fores pescar à cana na paraia acrescentas explicitamente que é *"no mar"* para saberem que tens de estar sempre a atirar a cana - é uma trabalheira pescar no mar.

Comment: @ClMend, eu não sei nada da pesca ao bodião, mas o que me parece mais provável é que o cabeceamento de quem está a cair de sono, com a cabeça a cair e a levantar logo de seguida, se assemelhe ao movimento que se dá ao anzol. Na pesca à linha de certas espécies faz-se isso, para atrair o peixe.

Comment: @bad_coder, não reconheço essas distinções. Na minha zona havia pessoal que ia pescar à cana no mar e dizia simplesmente que ia pescar. De qualquer maneira, o bodião é peixe de mar; nem deve haver grande pescaria de água doce na Madeira.

Comment: @Jacinto também faz sentido ser por semelhança, pois até a pescar "ao fundo" no mar é preciso estar sempre a atirar a cana portanto dormir enquanto se pesca nessas condições não faz grande sentido. Também presumo que eles na Madeira não se dedicam à pesca de água doce. (Setúbal é um caso particular por ter mar e rio.) Será que o CIMend está a falar da Madeia ilha, ou da [Madeira rio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeira_River) hehe?!

Comment: Pesca a cana não é so de água doce. Que ideia. Como já pesquei no mar e em água doce, sei do que estou falando. Eu moro na praia. Se eu falar ao meu vizinho, Hoje, vou pescar (e tenho a cana na mão), nunca pensaria que fosse pescar em água doce. Pensaria que eu iria pescar na praia ou das pedras (costeiras) ou de uma ponte sobre águas do mar. A cana não indica o tipo de pesca, mar ou água doce....